# Java logger forgets line number

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a Java application, which is using slf4j-logj412, version 1.7.25.  I'm instantiating a Logger with:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(SubsetAndProcess.class);
```

and my log4j pattern is:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and using standard `log.debug()` statements in a long loop which does some heavy processing.  It all behaves normally, but today on a single run, the output was:

```
...
2017-09-21 12:26:37 DEBUG SubsetAndProcess:569 - Processing row 40 of 1311
2017-09-21 12:26:38 DEBUG SubsetAndProcess:569 - Processing row 41 of 1311
2017-09-21 12:26:39 DEBUG SubsetAndProcess:569 - Processing row 42 of 1311
2017-09-21 12:26:40 DEBUG SubsetAndProcess:? - Processing row 43 of 1311
2017-09-21 12:26:41 DEBUG SubsetAndProcess:? - Processing row 44 of 1311
2017-09-21 12:26:42 DEBUG SubsetAndProcess:? - Processing row 45 of 1311
...
```

i.e. it forgot which line number it was logging.  This continued for the rest of the run.

It has never done so on previous runs.  It's not a big deal, but it's really weird, and I figured that if someone knew the answer, it could be quite illuminating as to the inner workings of Java, or at least the logger.

h2g2 related answers appreciated :)

Comment: whats your log4j pattern?

Comment: @nullpointer - Good point, I've added it.